# IE8 is not displaying php echo

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using the following code to display the current system time in a text field when the start button is hit. This code works fine in FireFox and Chrome, but IE 8 is not displaying the time and date when the start button is hit. It works if I hit the submit button.

Please advise what am I doing wrong here:

```
    <form name="form1" action='' method='post'>
    <table>
      <tr>
            <th>
            <p>Vendor was contacted at:</p>
            <button name="time" >Start</button><br>
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['start']))
            {
            $date_start = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');;
            $_SESSION['start'] = $date_start;
            }
            ?>
            <br>
            <input name="start" type="text" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['start']; ?>"
            <br>
            </th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>
           <br><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'><br>
        </th>
       </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: IE 8?  I'm so sorry, bro :(

Comment: questions like these eventually get flagged/deleted. It's a typo/syntax error deemed off-topic by the folks at Stack.

Comment: @Fred, Thanks for reply. Where did you see typo/syntax error. Please point that out.

Comment: Have a stroll through Stack by taking the tour; it's in there.

Comment: Tell you what: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, then come back and tell us what you get. Plus, view your HTML source. It's as good a tool as any. You may even see notices in there too.

Comment: the question has now gone stale. Moving on... *arrivederci*

Comment: @Fred-ii-, the code you suggested doesn't display any errors.

Comment: makes it harder not knowing what `<button name="time" >Start</button>` is supposed to do, ,unless it's irrelevant to the question. I also asked if the session was started which is also unclear and impossible to test without knowing if you have missing parts in your code or not.

Comment: ...and whether your file's extension is `.php`, where and how you're running this from... too many possibilities.

Comment: your code works; look at your HTML source (like I said earlier) `value="09-11-2015 17:45:24"` pulled from HTML source. what are you really trying to do here, pass it to another file? View the source in FF, you'll see an error in your input. Plus, error reporting SHOULD be throwing you this in the input `<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in <b>/var/usr/httdocs/folder/file.php</b> on line <b>???</b><br />`. So, I can't help you any more than I already have, sorry.

Comment: @adminhaq I posted an answer below. Please read through it carefully and in its entirety, and under my **Footnotes:** about the button itself. If you did see it, reload it; I made a few edits since I originally posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do read my answer in its entirety, including "Footnotes".

Besides the other answer given about the missing closing character for the input; not knowing whether the session has been started or not, am submitting the following answer.

Firstly, you said in comments that it isn't throwing any errors/notices.

> *"@Fred-ii-, the code you suggested doesn't display any errors. –  adminhaq 25 mins ago"*

If you didn't start the session, then you don't have error reporting setup properly or is not configured to "display" notices.

`session_start();` is required to reside inside all files using sessions. If you are trying to pass the data to another page, then that is also unclear.

The input itself should have contained something similar to:

```
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: _SESSION in <b>/var/usr/httdocs/folder/file.php</b> on line <b>(line number)</b>
```

for `value="<?php echo $_SESSION['start']; ?>"`, so it's best to use a ternary operator for this.

I.e.: `value="<?php echo !empty($_SESSION['start']) ? $_SESSION['start'] : ""; ?>"`

Fully tested code:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();

?>

<form name="form1" action='' method='post'>
<table>
  <tr>
        <th>
        <p>Vendor was contacted at:</p>
        <button name="time" >Start</button><br>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['start']))
        {
        $date_start = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');

        $_SESSION['start'] = $date_start;
        }
        ?>
        <br>

        <input name="start" type="text" class="textfield" value="<?php echo !empty($_SESSION['start']) ? $_SESSION['start'] : ""; ?>">

        <br>
        </th>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <th>
       <br><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'><br>
    </th>
   </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Sidenote: Forms do not hold the name attribute, so you can safely delete it from your declaration.

- Reload your file with my example code above without resubmitting, and you will see that the input will automatically populate itself.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Footnotes:

- **Make sure you don't have a cache problem.**
- Destroy the session and try again. [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

You may also have to change your button from:

```
<button name="time" >Start</button>
```

to

```
<button name="time" type="submit">Start</button>
```

which is the most likely issue, since I just remembered that I too had the same problem once with IE 8.

Sidenote: IE is a very picky browser. It might even not like the space in `<button name="time" >` yet, adding `type="submit"` is the most likely solution.

- Remember to view your HTML source; it's as good a tool as any when it comes to debugging.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The code I initially shared here is just a small portion of my php form. I am trying to collect data to see how long my vendors takes to respond to any of our requests. In my form, I added a start button, which captures the current time and puts it in the input field. The submit button takes all the form information and puts it in to a excel file. My original code works fine with Firefox, chrome, etc. except in IE. When click start, I don't see anything, but when I hit submit the input field gets populated. I used your code and it still doing the same thing.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH. My issue is resolved by following your footnote. I added the type="submit" as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML isn't valid.  You've forgotten the `>` on your `<input`

```
<input name="start" type="text" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['start']; ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But that didn't help. As far as I know, the <input doesn't need to have >.

Comment: You can lead a horse to water but you cannot make him drink @Fred-ii-

Comment: The sarcasm behind @RiggsFolly's comment it too damn high.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari that isn't sarcasm, it's called "humour".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sarcasm is a witty form of humor, more like a technical one but let's just not go there.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari George Carlin made a great career from it ;-) he was the best of them all.

Comment: @Fred-ii- aye aye captain! x)

Comment: @adminhaq: Actually, yes it does.  What you're thinking of is the fact that it doesn't need an associated `</input>`.  It's a self-closing tag.  `<input type="text"` is invalid `<input type="text">` is fine.